# Only one script source workable either ajax or jquery only. any solution pls?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I  got the following script src which i need jquery to do drag and drop div and I need ajax to do uploading in php. When I applied both script src only one workable which is top 1. Any solution to prevent this situation?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done also by adding

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

at before of ur end  tag.

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop using jQuery 1.6.4 (i.e. delete the first line of the code in the question).
2. Update any code that depends on obsolete features of jQuery to use whatever has replaced them in version 1.9.1. The [1.9 upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) can help with that.